# Reopen question on New York colors

Tags: discussion

Regarding this question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55326/what-is-the-color-that-reflect-new-york-city-most

This was closed as "primarily opinion-based" however it has a clear, easily stated answer and almost indisputable answer which I've placed in a comment.

> The colors would most likely be those of the of New York are Orange, White and Blue as seen on the [New York Flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flags_of_New_York_City). In addition these are used as the colors of the [Islanders - NHL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Islanders), [Knicks - NBL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Knicks), [Mets - Baseball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Mets) and [NYC FC - Soccer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City_FC).

It may, possibly, be off-topic for other reasons, but "opinion-based" it is not. Does this qualify for reopening?

Answer (score 1):

You say that your proposed answer is indisputable, but it sounds like it's just your opinion. There is no way to answer "what reflects X most" because "most" is entirely subjective. Unless there is a law or regulation somewhere that states "the colors that reflect the city of New York are x, y and z" then there is no answer to this question. Hence it was closed as unanswerable without involving opinions.